# Android Studio List file methods

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio

In Android Studio how do I get a list of the methods available for a file?

I recently switch from iOS to Android and this if the feature I miss the most from XCode. I assume it's a feature in Android, but I can't find it.

In XCode you click a drop down at the top of the window, it shows the method signatures of all of the methods on a file. You can click on each method to jump to its location in the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can see the **Structure** tab below your Project tab in Android Studio.

Open your file in editor and click on structure tab, it will show all the methods in the class selected.

Click on any method and you will be redirected to that method.

### [image]

In case you can't find that tab, you can add the tab using this sequence:

View -> Tool Windows -> Structure

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `CTRL + F12` shortcut in windows for that purpose.

Windows : **CTRL + F12**
MAC : **CMD + F12**

[image]

It will show you all the methods you have written in current opened file.